# Adding custom widget into Mapguide Maestro 4.0.1?

Tags: web-mapping, mapguide

I am developing a Web-Mapping application using **Mapguide Maestro 4.0.1**, in that I need to add a custom widget.

I'm looking for any suggestions for *how* and *where* to add the custom tools in the Mapguide Maestro. Is there any documentation for how to add the custom tools?

I am using MapGuide OpenSource 2.2, MapGide Maestro 4.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maestro has a user guide under `Help - User Guide`

If this documentation is not comprehensive enough, I would like to know the specifics so I can update this documentation with any missing information.

Comment: I have made search in `HELP - User Guide`; but I didn't find any doc regarding **to add a custom widget**. Can u please explain me with any screenshot or doc. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

hi Kishor? I just saw u do web development using openscales. I am new to flex development though I am really interested in the openscales. Could you have any tutorials on how to start off in this for a novice like me?I would really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: There is no specific tutorials for OpenScales, U have to go through demo application given in the [site](http://openscales.org/). Download the source code and try to develop your own application using the Flex API. You can get lot of support from the oprnscales developer group.